# Delete a project from SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

Does anyone know how to delete a project from a SonarQube server?

Thanks,
Ronen.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You have 2 ways to delete a project:

- If you are an admin of the project, you can delete it from its configuration actions

  => See ["Deleting a project" in the "Project Administration" documentation page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/project-settings/)
- If you are a SonarQube administrator, then you can also delete a project from the "Project Management" page

  => See ["Project Management/Project Existence" documentation page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/project-existence/)

Comment: Was having the same problem. Thanks for the screenshot, that really helped.

Comment: don't forget to log as an admin

Comment: This info is outdated ... see answer below for v3.3 of sonar.

Answer (score 18):

Updated for Sonar 2.11:

- Select the project (from the home page)
- Then click on the **Project Deletion** link on the bottom of the left panel
- Finally, confirm using the **Delete Project** button

Answer (score 12):

In Sonar 3.6, the deletion button is in the project page, under the search input, inside the menu Configuration (you must be logged as administrator):

[image]

Comment: Please note that this does not work in all browsers.  On OS X, for example, it works with Firefox but not Chrome or Safari.  This is an old bug from Sonar 3.x and is still present in 4.2.

Answer (score 9):

Login with administrator account. Select the project name. There you can see "project deletion" under configuration menu.

Answer (score 7):

Login with an administrator account, then browse to the settings page of your project to get the button "delete project".

Comment: for some reason, this button is absent. do you have an idea why?

Comment: Perhaps there is a sonar bug I am using sonar version 2.4.1 and I also have no idea how to delete the a project. No delete on the settings page of the project. Can you send a screen shot maybe we don't have ours set up correctly

Comment: Oops I am sorry I have just found it, I am sure it didn't show up the first time thou

Answer (score 6):

In some situations that you want to make it programatically you can use the SonarQube's Rest Web API to do so. According to [SonarQube documentation](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/projects):

```
POST api/projects/bulk_delete
```

Which can be used by passing the project's ID in the "**keys**" parameter.
I'm no pro in Curl but it should be something like this (code generated in the Postman client) for project with key "daBestProjectKey":

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 10a0e9a1-8dae-a9d1-45f2-0d8e56de999d" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" -F "keys=daBestProjectKey" "http://localhost:9000/api/projects/bulk_delete"
```

Answer (score 4):

[Home] button in top left corner >> [Projects] tab  in top left corner >> (under name, click on the name of your project) >> [Project Deletion] (on the left panel/dashboard at the bottom) >> [Delete project] (in the center of the page, kind of).

Answer (score 4):

## SonarQube 5.1

(released on April 23, 2015)
Consider that you need to have administrative permissions. You can perform as [described in the documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Administration#ProjectAdministration-DeletingaProject):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For **SonarQube 5.1**, following are the two options that can be followed:

[image: From Project Settings]

[image: From Administrator's Global Settings]

Answer (score 4):

Here is **SonarQube version 4.4**,

Seems each version the GUI is changed....

[image: in project viewer --> configuration --> delete]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the steps I use to DELETE any project from My SonarQube.

1. Login as administrator
2. Go to Administration -> Projects -> Projects Management
3. Select the Project(s) you want to DELETE
4. Click on Delete button at top right corner.

[image: Fig - Deleteing a Project From SonarQube]

Answer (score 1):

This information is for SonarQube version 5.0 which is latest for now - Released on 17th January 2015

You can delete the project from Project Configuration which is present on right hand side of Project Dashboard.The same screenshot is attached below.

[image]

if you are an Administrator of SonarQube, the you have the authority to delete multiple projects.

Just go to settings and you see a tab on your left as "bulk deletion". Please find the attached screenshot for the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sonar Admin login with uwr: admin and pwd: admin (default one) --> Setting -->Bulk Deletion -->select projects you want to delete and delete.