# SonarQube: Failed to restart after deleting project

Tags: sonarqube

coming from:  [Elasticsearch failed to recover after crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667063/elasticsearch-failed-to-recover-after-crash#)  and [Delete a project from SonarQube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658131/delete-a-project-from-sonarqube)

I deleted a project and then went to cli and did a restart and now the it fialed with :

```
2015.05.08 15:10:57 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2015.05.08 15:10:57 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
2015.05.08 15:10:58 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1431061857323] version[1.4.4], pid[6991], build[c88f77f/2015-02-19T13:05:36Z]
2015.05.08 15:10:58 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1431061857323] initializing ...
2015.05.08 15:10:58 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1431061857323] loaded [], sites []
2015.05.08 15:10:59 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1431061857323] initialized
2015.05.08 15:10:59 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1431061857323] starting ...
2015.05.08 15:11:00 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1431061857323] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.78.76:9001]}
2015.05.08 15:11:00 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1431061857323] sonarqube/KkVXWlQCRLGbdSgJZT90uA
2015.05.08 15:11:03 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1431061857323] new_master [sonar-1431061857323][KkVXWlQCRLGbdSgJZT90uA][java-ci.gbst.net][inet[/192.168.78.76:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1431061857323}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2015.05.08 15:11:03 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1431061857323] started
2015.05.08 15:11:04 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1431061857323] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
2015.05.08 15:11:45 WARN   es[o.e.indices.cluster]  [sonar-1431061857323] [sourcelines][0] failed to start shard
org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [sourcelines][0] failed to recover shard
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:287) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:132) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_75]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_75]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.translog.TranslogCorruptedException: translog corruption while reading from stream
        at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.ChecksummedTranslogStream.read(ChecksummedTranslogStream.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:257) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: No version type match [34]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.VersionType.fromValue(VersionType.java:307) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog$Create.readFrom(Translog.java:374) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.ChecksummedTranslogStream.read(ChecksummedTranslogStream.java:68) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
2015.05.08 15:11:45 WARN   es[o.e.c.action.shard]  [sonar-1431061857323] [sourcelines][0] sending failed shard for [sourcelines][0], node[KkVXWlQCRLGbdSgJZT90uA], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [PPjSIrsGT4SmdwDQigKHgA], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[sourcelines][0] failed to recover shard]; nested: TranslogCorruptedException[translog corruption while reading from stream]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No version type match [34]]; ]]
2015.05.08 15:11:45 WARN   es[o.e.c.action.shard]  [sonar-1431061857323] [sourcelines][0] received shard failed for [sourcelines][0], node[KkVXWlQCRLGbdSgJZT90uA], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [PPjSIrsGT4SmdwDQigKHgA], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[sourcelines][0] failed to recover shard]; nested: TranslogCorruptedException[translog corruption while reading from stream]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No version type match [34]]; ]]
```

How would i be able to restart. some where i need to clean up the translog but i cant seem to find how can i do that.

Edit: I deleted the non zero translog file and restarted and it gave the same error and recreated the 17B translog file again. So that didnt help.

Thanks
Syed

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the embedded ElasticSearch index is corrupt. You will have to stop the server, remove the contents of directory `$SQ_HOME/data/es` and restart the server. This should build the ES index clean.

Comment: But will take a long time:
2016.10.11 15:27:23 INFO  ce[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting ce
2016.10.11 15:27:23 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.a.WebServerBarrier] Waiting for Web Server to be operational...
2016.10.11 15:27:24 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.a.WebServerBarrier] Still waiting for WebServer...
2016.10.11 15:27:26 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.a.WebServerBarrier] Still waiting for WebServer...
2016.10.11 15:27:31 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.a.WebServerBarrier] Still waiting for WebServer...
2016.10.11 15:27:44 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.a.WebServerBarrier] Still waiting for WebServer...
20 minutes and still waiting.....